# Should Oauth audience be different between staging and production environments

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt

I have an API secured using Oauth that I'm exposing in a staging environment and production environment. For proper security, should the *audience* for the API be different between staging and production?

If the audience is the same between the two environments, wouldn't this allow a single access token to be used to access the API in both production and staging?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `issuer` claim should be different for each stage of your deployment pipeline. The `audience` claim is often a logical name that represents components and can be the same in all environments.

**TOKENS ISSUED TO A CLIENT**

An access token might contain these built-in claims:

- Issuer: https://login-staging.example.com
- Audience: api.example.com
- Scope: orders products

An ID token might contain these:

- Issuer: https://login-staging.example.com
- Audience: my-web-app

**VALIDATING JWTs in APIs**

Typical code is shown below and should verify both issuer and audience. This ensures that each environment rejects tokens from other environments, and returns a 401 response if issuer or audience checks fail.

```js
const jwksEndpoint = 'https://login.example.com/.well-known/jwks';
const remoteJWKSet = createRemoteJWKSet(new URL(jwksEndpoint));

function validateJwtAccessToken(accessToken) {

    const options = {
        algorithms: ['RS256'],
        issuer: 'https://login-staging.example.com',
        audience: 'api.example.com',
    };
    const result = await jwtVerify(accessToken, remoteJWKSet, options);
    const claims = result.payload;
    return claims;
}
```

**MULTIPLE APIs**

A shared audience is sometimes used between multiple APIs from the same owner. If you are developing an `orders` API that calls a `products` API, the audience can be the same for both. This enables the JWT to be forwarded between APIs, so that both receive a verifiable user identity.

Each API should then validate the JWT, and also check that the token has the scopes that API requires, from the JWT payload. If this is not the case, eg the products API does not receive its required scope, it will return a 403 forbidden response.

Comment: Got it. That makes sense. Thank you!

A bit unrelated to the main question but something I've been thinking about. When a public `orders` API makes a call to a separate, internal `products` service, would it typically send the decoded token or would each internal service need to verify+decode the token?

Comment: From a security viewpoint is is best if each API verifies the JWT. Sometimes this is referred to as a zero trust architecture, with strong protection against internal threats. It is more secure than passing secure values such as user IDs and tenant IDs in unverifiable headers that could potentially be altered by a malicious party. At a code level this is pretty simple in each API. You will need to test expiry and retry behaviour - though I suspect you are probably doing that already.